# In Webflux context What is the difference between WebFilter and ExchangeFilterFunction?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I stumbled upto two classes `ExchangeFilterFunction` and `WebFilter`. What is the difference between them and where is the right place to use them?

Answer (score 0):

`ExchangeFilterFunction` and `WebFilter` are both used in the context of Spring WebFlux for handling web requests, but they are used in different scenarios and have different purposes.

`ExchangeFilterFunction` is used with `WebClient`, which is a non-blocking, reactive client to perform HTTP requests. `ExchangeFilterFunction` can be used to transform the request or the response before it's sent or after it's received. For example, you can add headers or log requests. It's typically used when you're making outbound HTTP requests.

On the other hand, `WebFilter` is used for processing incoming HTTP requests in a non-blocking way before they reach the actual handlers (like controllers). You can think of it as the reactive equivalent of a Servlet Filter. It's typically used when you're building a server that's receiving HTTP requests.

In summary, use `ExchangeFilterFunction` when you're making outbound HTTP requests with `WebClient`, and use `WebFilter` when you're building a server that's receiving inbound HTTP requests.